# Drag&Drop into brower window - prevent default firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to make a Drag&Drop possibility on my page.

I have to prevent the default actions for the browser, when a file is dragged into the window. Here is my code:

```
document.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

How do I prevent the default actions for Firefox?

*** FOUND OUT ***

The dragover event also has to be cancelled for firefox to listen to the drop event.

```
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The dragover event has to be cancelled also for Firefox to listen to the drop event:

```
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use dragleave

```
    document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
    });
```